# php script to download files from a repeating node of an xml feed

Tags: php, file, download, feed

I need to parse a huge xml feed containing games data and download all the games through the url node of each repeating item to my server.

I have no problem parsing the xml feed, I need to know the best way to download the files from their remote site to my server. Also bear in mind that the feed contains several thousands of items.

Comment: Please mention your problems. XML reading or file downloading or ?

Comment: my problem is file downloading. I already parse the xml feed using the simpleXML library. I`m not a php guru so I need the best way to download the files and also need to know is it ok to issue the command to download the thousands of files in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the php file_get_contents()/file_put_contents() which is very easy to use and works perfectly. The only problem I have now is that if I try to grab around 50+ games at once, sometimes the server returns an error and I have to request less number say 25 games to be able to get them without problem. Anyway I can ask the server to get me huge amount say 500-1000 game without throwing an error?